# How to filter nested fields in rethinkdb

Tags: rethinkdb

How to query and return all channels with matching channelId, from a document:

As an example, my rethink table contains the following document:

```
{
  "agreement_id": "5",
  "channels": [
    {
      "channelId": "8deb-6b37-4678115-917d-ad365ae57e19",
      "lab_cost": 333,
      "learner_cost": 30,
      "net_revenue": 20.87,
      "orgId": "gmudam",
      "publisher": "oci-jumpstart",
      "publisher_revenue": 4.97,
      "ql_revenue": 16.9,
      "realm_cost": 1.13
    },
    {
      "channelId": "8deb-6b37-4678115-917d-ad365ae57e19",
      "lab_cost": 444,
      "learner_cost": 30,
      "net_revenue": 20.87,
      "orgId": "gmudam",
      "publisher": "oci-jumpstart",
      "publisher_revenue": 4.97,
      "ql_revenue": 16.9,
      "realm_cost": 1.13
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract all channels by channelId from a document, you can do the following:

```
r.db("DB").table("TABLE").get("agreement_id")("channels")
     .filter(function(channel){ 
       return channel("channelId").eq("8deb-6b37-4678115-917d-ad365ae57e19")})
```

This will give you all channels with the id "8deb-6b37-4678115-917d-ad365ae57e19". E.g:

```
[
    {
      "channelId": "8deb-6b37-4678115-917d-ad365ae57e19",
      "lab_cost": 333,
      "learner_cost": 30,
      "net_revenue": 20.87,
      "orgId": "gmudam",
      "publisher": "oci-jumpstart",
      "publisher_revenue": 4.97,
      "ql_revenue": 16.9,
      "realm_cost": 1.13
    },
    {
      "channelId": "8deb-6b37-4678115-917d-ad365ae57e19",
      "lab_cost": 444,
      "learner_cost": 30,
      "net_revenue": 20.87,
      "orgId": "gmudam",
      "publisher": "oci-jumpstart",
      "publisher_revenue": 4.97,
      "ql_revenue": 16.9,
      "realm_cost": 1.13
    }
  ]
```